# Disable Google Calendar notifications for a specific event (Slack and Android)

Tags: google-calendar, slack

I'm surprised this is so difficult.

The company I'm working at uses Google Calendar to schedule meetings. We were recently told to add recurring events to block off times when we're not available for meeting (i.e. when we're commuting or sleeping). However, even though I set the event to "no notifications", I still get notifications through Google Calendar for Slack and Google Calendar for Android.

For Android, it seems like I can disable notifications for x minutes before the event, but I'll always get a notification exactly when the event occurs. For Slack, I can enable reminders for all events or no events; I can't disable reminders for specific events.

Is there a way to make Google Calendar ignore events on my calendar, but make them show up when a co-worker tries to schedule a meeting with me?